App closing when use virtual threads factory
I have this peace of code
public static void main(String[] args){

  ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(Thread.ofVirtual().factory());

  executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> System.out.println("A"), 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> System.out.println("B"), 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

}

When I run this code, the app close instantly with code 0.
But if I use Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); without Virtual factory, the app is no longer closing and the scheduled threads are running infinitely.

Virtual threads are daemon threads, they don't hold up JVM exit. Just await  termination of the executor.

@DuncG, for awaitTermination I need to specify a timeout. But I want to be endless.

@DuncG, I was trying with Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread(); synchronized(mainThread){ mainThread.wait(); } and is working. Do you think my way is ok?

While the linked Q&A shall help gather more details, the short answer is that ExecutorService making use of a virtual thread factory cannot be scheduled in a straightforward manner.
